# setting layout 9 patch image in background programmatically not working fine

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, nine-patch

here is xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_chatdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="date"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/chattab_messsagelayout_marginbottom"
        android:textSize="@dimen/chattab_textview_date_fontsize"
        android:textColor="@color/chattab_textview_date_fontcolor"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayout_chatlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_chatdate"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/chattab_messsagelayout_margintop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/chattab_messsagelayout_marginleft"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/chattab_messsagelayout_marginleft"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/aqua"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_chatname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="username"
            android:textSize="@dimen/chattab_edittext_message_fontsize"
            android:textColor="@color/chattab_textview_chatname_fontcolor"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_chatmessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="message here"
            android:textSize="@dimen/chattab_edittext_message_fontsize"
            android:textColor="@color/chattab_textview_date_fontcolor"
            android:maxLines="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>





  if(broadcastResponse.getUid().equals(uId))
                    {
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)  holder.messageLayout.getLayoutParams();
                       params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
           params.setMargins(0,0,R.dimen.chattab_llayout_chatlayout_marginright,0);
                        holder.messageLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                        holder.messageLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aqua);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)  holder.messageLayout.getLayoutParams();
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                        params.setMargins(0, 0, R.dimen.chattab_llayout_chatlayout_marginright, 0);
                        holder.messageLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                        holder.messageLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                    }
```

**

holder.messageLayout is the LinearLayout having id:llayout_chatlayout in xml see image it should display image same as aqua and align right
while right now its not setting image properly.how to solve this issue
? i already have all 9 patch images in all folders in hdpi ,
mdpi,xhdpi ,xxhdpi

now i m using 9 patch image programmmatically in my adapter class
but the image i m setting using java in not working fine while xml
image is displayed correctly.how can i align  right the layout with grey image while align left with aqua image inside condition.

[image: image issue]

Comment: It seems the effect of a **badly scaled** 9 patch. Make sure the 9 patch markers are **1 px** wide. And **pure black on a transparent** background. Also, the extension must be **.9.png**, not **.png**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein  yes .9.png is already set

Answer (score 0):

You can set your as per direction of message coming.
i have put some code for your understanding.
You can put this code in your adapter class.

```
 private void setAlignment(ViewHolder holder, boolean isOutgoing) {
        if (!isOutgoing) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.content.getLayoutParams();
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);

            layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtInfo.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            holder.txtInfo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            if (holder.txtMessage != null) {
                holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.incoming_message_bg);
                layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            } else {
                holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            }
        } else {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.content.getLayoutParams();
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);

            layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtInfo.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            holder.txtInfo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            if (holder.txtMessage != null) {
                holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outgoing_message_bg);
                layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            } else {
                holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Xml:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/incoming_message_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:maxWidth="250dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is layoutParams  ?

Comment: contentWithBG and txtMessage whats the difference between them

Comment: contentWithBG  is an linearlayout where you have to put your nine patch image as background and put textview in that linear laout where you will put your text message

Comment: actually i  have two textviews inside my linearlayout  and same linearlayout  should contain background image and align property pls see my xml

Comment: you can also set two textview or put your second textview outside the layout. just try this code

Comment: why second textview outside the layout  i want both textview iside the layout ?

Comment: so set two textview in that layout. It's not a big deal

Comment: yes i agreed its not big deal ...but its not setting the alignmenet to the right of layout ?

Comment: set  layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89993/discussion-between-erum-and-user3559670).

Comment: u are not reading my layout ...once i m trying to use linearlayout in  java i m getting error ?